# Setting state inside useEffect is breaking my data structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I tried to set state in my useEffect hook but it returned an infinitely nested object instead of a flat collection:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading || error) return;
    let { items } = data;
    items = items.map(r => ({
      ...r,
      questionData: JSON.parse(r.data),
      updatedAt: format(new Date(`${r.updatedAt}.000Z`), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    }));

    setItems(items);
  }, [loading, error, data]);
```

Expecting this:

[image]

but got this instead:

[image]

Comment: What is `items` initially?

Comment: items is a collection of objects [{},{},{}], like in the expected image, but for some reason when I try to set it, it turns into an array of nested objects that never ends `[{{{{{}}}}}, {{{{{}}}}} ]`

Comment: The fact that you're getting `items` from `data`, but then setting it like `setItems(items)` make me very suspicious that the issue has to do with your updating pattern and not the loop. Can you show how you declare the state hook?

Comment: I do it like this `const [items, setItems] = useState([]);`

Comment: Im not a fan of the duplicate variable name `items`. Could they be conflicting?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this. Are you able to create a reproducible example?

Comment: I don't think item is a collection of objects [{},{},{}] it seems a lot that the items holds references to data (or items itself). Can you show what is a __real__ content of data.items? To reject that hypothesis, you may simply JSON.stringify(items) which will fail if you have circular reference...

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading || error) return;
    let { items } = data;
    items = items.map(r => ({
      ...r,
      questionData: JSON.parse(r.data),
      updatedAt: format(new Date(`${r.updatedAt}.000Z`), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    }));

    setItems(items);
  }, [loading, error, data]);
```

Why have you set a state called items, and inside your useEffect, set a local variable called items? That's going to cause problems.

Just change your local variable to a name that makes more sense and doesn't conflict with your state.

```
let dataItems = data;
dataItems = dataItems.map(dataItem => ({...})
```